# Django: filter ForeignKey in value or None

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Can I get the following to work without resorting to two queries?

```
>>> c = Category.objects.all()[0]
>>> len(Document.objects.filter(category=c))
3
>>> len(Document.objects.filter(category=None))
55
>>> len(Document.objects.filter(category__in=[c, None]))
3
```

Comment: what result is expected?

Comment: If you want the counts for all categories, `Document.objects.values('category').annotate(count=Count('category')).order_by()`

Comment: Didn't actually want the count.  That was just for illustrative purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Q` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

```
from django.db.models import Q
len(Document.objects.filter( Q(category=c) | Q(category=None) ) )
```

Comment: @agf Actually this is not effective if you intend to evaluate queryset anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Q objects provide the functionality you are loking for. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects